# What's the order of casting datatype and comparing two objects in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
dataset.filter(col.cast("string") === "1")
```

I want to filter a dataset based on the column named `col`. However, I don't know what's the actual datatype of `col`. So before comparing it to `"1"`, I cast `col` to string type. But this code does not work correctly. It returns zero rows. But if I dropped the `cast` function, it gives correct result. It seems Spark compares `col` and `"1"` before casting `col` to string type.

So, I checked the execution plan:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Filter (cast(a3#5 as string) = "1")
+- LogicalRDD [a1#3, a2#4, a3#5]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
a1: double, a2: double, a3: double
Filter (cast(a3#5 as string) = "1")
+- LogicalRDD [a1#3, a2#4, a3#5]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (isnotnull(a3#5) && (cast(a3#5 as string) = "1"))
+- LogicalRDD [a1#3, a2#4, a3#5]

== Physical Plan ==
*Filter (isnotnull(a3#5) && (cast(a3#5 as string) = "1"))
+- Scan ExistingRDD[a1#3,a2#4,a3#5]
```

What confused me is that the execution plan showing Spark compares `col` and `"1"` after the `cast` function.

Comment: can you share the schema of your dataset?

Comment: a1: DoubleType, a2: DoubleType, a3: DoubleType

Comment: you don't have a column named col so how come your question says so.?

Answer (score 0):

```
Below example works fine:

val seq = Seq((1, 23, 1, 1), (1, 45, 2, 2), (1, 91, 3, 3), (1, 90, 4, 4), (1, 71, 5, 5), (1, 42, 6, 6), (1, 72, 7, 7), (1, 44, 8, 8), (1, 55, 9, 9), (1, 21, 0, 0))
val df = sc.parallelize(seq).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")
df.printSchema
root
 |-- c1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- c2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- c3: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- c4: integer (nullable = false)

df.show
+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1| 23|  1|  1|
|  1| 45|  2|  2|
|  1| 91|  3|  3|
|  1| 90|  4|  4|
|  1| 71|  5|  5|
|  1| 42|  6|  6|
|  1| 72|  7|  7|
|  1| 44|  8|  8|
|  1| 55|  9|  9|
|  1| 21|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+

df.filter($"c3".cast("string") === "1").show
+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1| 23|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+
```